# Replace callbacks by Kotlin Coroutine on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How can I replace my callbacks with coroutine? It's possible?
I tried to replace my onclick event of adapter item using suspendCoroutine:

```
suspend fun waitForButtonClick() = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
    button.setOnClickListener {
        continuation.resume("My Data")
    }
}
```

And on activity:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
  val callbackResult = adapter.waitForButtonClick()
}
```

The problem is that I can call waitForButtonClick only one time, because resume can be executed only one time.
How to replace the onClickCallback with Kotlin coroutine?

Comment: Could you please expand the usage example? How do you expect it to work if the handler is clicked multiple times?

Comment: You can replace the `OnClickListener` reference to the one you need afterwards, and only then resume the continuation

Comment: but when I tri to call resume, the coroutine trow an error that I can call resume only a time

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that calling setOnClickListener overwrites the old listener.

you can use something like this to collect the suspended functions:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    button.setOnClickListener(this::resumeSuspendedClickFunctions)
}

private val suspendedClickFunctions = LinkedList<View.OnClickListener>()

private fun resumeSuspendedClickFunctions(view: View){
    suspendedClickFunctions.forEach {
        it.onClick(view)
    }
    suspendedClickFunctions.clear()
}

suspend fun waitForButtonClick() = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
    val listener = View.OnClickListener {
        continuation.resume("My Data")
    }
    suspendedClickFunctions.add(listener)
}
```

Comment: `suspendedClickFunctions.forEach ` may yeild ConcurrentModificationException if a new listener is added from a callback